# selenium | How do I click because there is value I use VB.net language | how is the coding ...?

Tags: vb.net, selenium, visual-studio-2017

```
<p>12 Diamond</p><input class="valueOptionProduct" name="ValueOptionProduct" type="radio" value="10">
```

**I have tried the following coding, but failed**

```
Driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("valueOptionProduct")).Click()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OP7Je.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is OK
But before you use it, you have to ensure that you did the following :

```
   1.Install Selenium.WebDriver by Selenium Commities from 
   Tools->NuGet Package Manager->Manage NuGet Packages for Solution ... ->
   Browse->Selenium.WebDriver

   2.Add in your code 
   Imports OpenQA.Selenium
   Imports OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome - if you use Chrome version

   3. Before row 
   Driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("valueOptionProduct")).Click()
   add 
   Dim Driver As IWebDriver = New ChromeDriver("Path to your directory containing ChromeDriver.exe")
```

Comment: thank you for your answer
for coding that I use as your reply
but every time I use the code it's always an error,
Maybe there is a value, huh?

Comment: <div class="group-item clearfix"><!----><div class="wrapper-item"><p>12 Diamond</p><input class="valueOptionProduct" name="ValueOptionProduct" type="radio" value="10"></div><div class="wrapper-item"><p>50 Diamond</p><input class="valueOptionProduct" name="ValueOptionProduct" type="radio" value="11"></div><div class="wrapper-item"><p>70 Diamond</p><input class="valueOptionProduct" name="ValueOptionProduct" type="radio" value="12"></div></div>

Comment: OK - now i can try with your html code - you can save it in a file-D:/tst.htm
and use this code
    Dim driver As IWebDriver = New ChromeDriver()
 driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("D://tst.htm")
 ' Get element with value '10'
 driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@name='ValueOptionProduct' and  @value='10']")).Click()

You can change 10 with 11 or 12 to see choosing different radio buttons

Comment: Yeayy ...
Thank you sir for the help, honestly I am just a beginner and I have been looking for coding for 7 days
for your help I can solve my problem
Once again, thank you